# UK visa refused (Pakistani nationals) due to funds parking - need advice on fresh application

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens, uae, proof-provenance-of-funds

Recently my parents and I applied for a UK general visitor visa. My father's visa was rejected due to an influx of funds in his account. Furthermore, my mother’s application was also subsequently rejected as she was funded by my father for the trip.

With regards to my application. I was funding my own trip and had a total of 13000 AED in my account (2380 GBP).I stated in my application that I had no other savings and that the trip would cost me 1000 GBP.

Kindly note that I have previous lived in UK for 4 years as a student and left the country before my visa expired.

Visa application feedback stated that:

1. I was using a significant portioning of my savings to fund the trip and this was considered unjustified.
2. Secondly, since i am single and have no saving in UAE. It was considered probable that I might not return at the end of my trip.

I have the following questions:

1. When should I reapply? I am considering applying only for myself and my mother this time and funding her for the trip.
2. What assurance can I provide to prove that I have a genuine reason to return to UAE at the end of my trip?
3. Is it possible that my visa was rejected because my parents visas were rejected?

Comment: Do you have a job to return to in the UAE? A house/flat on a long term lease? Family? Strong ties to the community there, eg member of a sports group, key member in a religious group etc?

Comment: `1` is very detrimental to your application. See it from the visa officer's view, spending all of your savings to visit a country as a tourist, a very big red flag. `2` then adds weight to the visa officer's point that you are trying to emigrate under the guise of visiting UK. And funds being transferred just before a visa application is always going to be a red flag.

Comment: Yes i have a job in uae and i provided my salary certificate etc. as proof. i have my family in UAE but the feedback stated that i don't have any dependents or saving in UAE hence i have no strong reason to return at the end of trip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not immigration officers or lawyers. We help where we can based on previous experience of ours and others but once you are rejected, this is lawyer territory.

Comment: @MohammadWaqarAzeem, It's not a legal advice forum, but we can help out on very specific issues that are ALWAYS included in best practices anyway. You should include the text from your refusal notice if you want the best results. Your problem with spending a disproportionate amount on your visit has no further information, what are we supposed to do?  Fix your question to include the refusal formulae and then ask specific questions about it.  It will probably attract an informed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Savings are a factor but the major factor is a steady income in your place of residence that assures your return to your country of residence. Not having a source of income would seriously hamper your chances of getting a visa. Having immovable properties and investments are also a big plus when applying for a visa. They do not look at the total amount you have in your bank account, they are more concerned with where and how the money is coming from.

Having returned within the visa time frame as a student is not a guarantee that you would get a visitors visa.

You should apply when you have a source of income and a reasonable amount of money in your savings/investments. Having GBP3000-4000 in total savings makes it look a bit odd.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I will probably apply again in a while.